# Getting date time string into google calendar format

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

I have a c# DateTime object and I'm trying to convert it to a google calendar event link date time string. I use a calendar link generator [here](https://decomaan.github.io/google-calendar-link-generator/) and I get a date time string that looks like this

> dates=20170829T180000Z%2F20170829T190000Z

where the start time is 11:00AM and the second time is 12:00PM

how do I format my string to get this?

I have this so far

```
var FormattedStartDateTime = newEvent.EventDateTime.ToString("yyyyDDmm")
```

this will get me the date but how do I get the rest? I think the rest is in seconds, maybe from Jan 1, but not sure and is there a way to include the 'T' and 'Z' at the end? Or do I need to create my own string like this after I get the seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
Date.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
var output = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}T{0:HHmmss}Z%2F{1:yyyyMMdd}T{1:HHmmss}Z", startDateTime, endDateTime);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this might be better but not sure. XmlConvert.ToString(newEvent.EventDateTime, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc) but this gives me "2017-09-04T05:00:00Z" is there a way to get it without the dashes and coloons or should I just remove them

Comment: something isn't calculating correctly here with the seconds. I have a start time of Sept 6 @ 5AM and ends at 6AM. The string you gave me creates this "20170906T050000Z%2F20170906T060000Z" but when I click on the link in my email it opens up a calendar event in google calendar that is set for 9/5/2017 at 10PM to 11PM 9/5/2017

Comment: Probably because the time is in UTC format (essentially the British time zone). You will need to convert from local time to UTC before formatting the string.

Comment: If you post your revised code maybe I can see what the problem is.